# Is it possible to launch MacVim NOT in full screen mode?

Tags: macos, mac, vim, vi, macvim

Whenever I Launch MacVim it takes up the whole screen. I don't want this. Is there any way to prevent it from happening?

I run OS X 10.8.

Comment: Hmm.. That's odd. It's never done that for me. Are you sure you haven't edited a config?

Answer (score 8):

Are you setting the (*MacVim*-specific) `fullscreen` option in any of your configuration files?

You can use the following command (in a fresh *MacVim* window, before taking it out of fullscreen mode) to find out whether and where it is being set automatically:

```
:verbose set fullscreen?
```

If it says `nofullscreen`, then this is not the problem. If it says `fullscreen`, it should also mention the configuration file that last set the option (it will not mention a file if you have set/reset it manually: e.g. by manually taking it into or out of fullscreen mode). You might need to edit the file named in the `verbose set` output (or maybe override it from a different configuration file).

Comment: I received nofullscreen as output for that command, but macvim is always starting in fullscreen

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was good enough to comment out the fullscreen part of the config file found under `~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/extended.vim`.

Look for the `if has("gui_macvim")` in that file and comment out that entire block and you should be able to start MacVim in windows mode.

Side note, I've also turned off the native fullscreen support for MacVim since I dislike it. You can do that via:

```
$ defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMNativeFullScreen 0
```

in a Terminal.

Comment: thanks, that is the right answer. That file indeed has a section in it `if has("gui_macvim")` that is specific to MacVim. and commenting the relevant lines out does sort the problem 